# Jquery- noConflict() not suit for opera?

Tags: javascript, jquery, opera

I have added many jquery plugins in one page. and I use `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` I tested well under IE6, IE8 and firefox4. But in opera10, it just show the first jQuery effective. I guess the problem is in `jQuery.noConflict()`, is it not suit for opera?

Comment: Sorry, I want to, but there are too many code need to post, and I'm not used to post a  `backticks` out of the code, I can not find `backticks` in my keyword, sometimes I copy it from other place, you know many forum just use [ code ] [ /code ]...

Comment: Just post a link to a page where we can see the problem, it will help us understand it :)

Answer (score 1):

[`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) works fine in Opera - it sounds like you most likely have a `<script>` include issue that browsers are handling differently, for example an invalid self-closing `<script />` tag, code within the same tag with a `src` attribute, etc.

Comment: Thanks, nick. I will check for myself again under your advice.